# Dice Roll in Python GUI

Tags: python, dice

I am trying to figure out how to roll a pair of dice in the Python GUI using the `randint` function.

I want to use two mouse clicks to generate two numbers for the dice rolls from `randint`, and use two more clicks to change the dice to show these numbers.

I have the dice displayed and everything, but I'm uncertain how to use the `randint` and `mouseclick` functions in relation to the dice in the window for this project. Usage of `randint` and `mouseclick` is mandatory for this project. I've been trying to use a `list` to randomly remove, or not, the dots from the dice, but the trouble is there doesn't seem to be an efficient way to do this using `randint`. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
from graphics import *

def main():


    #Set interface
    w = GraphWin()
    s1 = Rectangle(Point(70,70), Point(20,20))
    s1.setFill("Green")
    s1.setOutline("Black")
    s1.draw(w)


    s2 = Rectangle(Point(140, 140), Point (90,90))
    s2.setFill("Green")
    s2.setOutline("Black")
    s2.draw(w)

    center = Point(60,60)
    ds1 = Circle(center, 5)
    ds1.setFill("Red")
    ds1.draw(w)

    center2 = Point(45,60)
    ds2 = Circle(center2, 5)
    ds2.setFill("Red")
    ds2.draw(w)

    center3 = Point(30,60)
    ds3 = Circle(center3, 5)
    ds3.setFill("Red")
    ds3.draw(w)

    center4 = Point(30,30)
    ds4 = Circle(center4, 5)
    ds4.setFill("Red")
    ds4.draw(w)

    center5 = Point(45,30)
    ds5 = Circle(center5, 5)
    ds5.setFill("Red")
    ds5.draw(w)

    center6 = Point(60,30)
    ds6 = Circle(center6, 5)
    ds6.setFill("Red")
    ds6.draw(w)

    center7 = Point(130,130)
    ds7 = Circle(center7, 5)
    ds7.setFill("Red")
    ds7.draw(w)

    center8 = Point(130,115)
    ds8 = Circle(center8, 5)
    ds8.setFill("Red")
    ds8.draw(w)

    center9 = Point(130,100)
    ds9 = Circle(center9, 5)
    ds9.setFill("Red")
    ds9.draw(w)

    center10 = Point(100,100)
    ds10 = Circle(center10, 5)
    ds10.setFill("Red")
    ds10.draw(w)

    center11 = Point(100,115)
    ds11 = Circle(center11, 5)
    ds11.setFill("Red")
    ds11.draw(w)

    center12 = Point(100,130)
    ds12 = Circle(center12, 5)
    ds12.setFill("Red")
    ds12.draw(w)

    #Display message
    m = Text(Point(1,3), ("Click to roll dice: "))
    m.draw(w)
```

## Lab4.py

```
from graphics import *
from random import*
def main():
    print ("This program rolls dice using randint")

    w = GraphWin()
    s1 = Rectangle(Point(70,70), Point(20,20))
    s1.setFill("Green")
    s1.setOutline("Black")
    s1.draw(w)

    s2 = Rectangle(Point(140, 140), Point (90,90))
    s2.setFill("Green")
    s2.setOutline("Black")
    s2.draw(w)

    #Display message
    m = Text(Point(1,3), ("Click to roll dice: "))
    m.draw(w)

    center = Point(60,60)
    sd1 = Circle(center, 5)
    sd1.setFill("Red")

    center = Point(45,60)
    sd2 = Circle(center, 5)
    sd2.setFill("Red")

    center3 = Point(30,60)
    sd3 = Circle(center3, 5)
    sd3.setFill("Red")

    center4 = Point(30,30)
    sd4 = Circle(center4, 5)
    sd4.setFill("Red")

    center5 = Point(45,30)
    sd5 = Circle(center5, 5)
    sd5.setFill("Red")

    center6 = Point(60,30)
    sd6 = Circle(center6, 5)
    sd6.setFill("Red")

    center7 = Point(130,130)
    sd7 = Circle(center7, 5)
    sd7.setFill("Red")

    center8 = Point(130,115)
    sd8 = Circle(center8, 5)
    sd8.setFill("Red")

    center9 = Point(130,100)
    sd9 = Circle(center9, 5)
    sd9.setFill("Red")

    center10 = Point(100,100)
    sd10 = Circle(center10, 5)
    sd10.setFill("Red")

    center11 = Point(100,115)
    sd11 = Circle(center11, 5)
    sd11.setFill("Red")

    center12 = Point(100,130)
    sd12 = Circle(center12, 5)
    sd12.setFill("Red")

    w.getMouse()
    RN = randint(0,5)
    if RN == 0:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw
    elif RN == 1:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw
        sd2.draw
    elif RN == 2:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw
        sd2.draw
        sd3.draw
    elif RN == 3:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw
        sd2.draw
        sd3.draw
        sd4.draw
    elif RN == 4:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw
        sd2.draw
        sd3.draw
        sd4.draw
        sd5.draw
    elif RN == 5:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw
        sd2.draw
        sd3.draw
        sd4.draw
        sd5.draw
        sd6.draw

        w.getMouse()
        RN = randint(0,5)
        if RN == 0:
                w.getMouse()
                sd7.draw
        elif RN == 1:
                w.getMouse()
                sd7.draw
                sd8.draw
        elif RN == 2:
                w.getMouse()
                sd7.draw
                sd8.draw
                sd9.draw
        elif RN == 3:
                w.getMouse()
                sd7.draw
                sd8.draw
                sd9.draw
                sd10.draw
        elif RN == 4:
                w.getMouse()
                sd7.draw
                sd8.draw
                sd9.draw
                sd10.draw
                sd11.draw
        elif RN == 5:
                w.getMouse()
                sd7.draw
                sd8.draw
                sd9.draw
                sd10.draw
                sd11.draw
                sd12.draw

                #Change message
                m = Text(Point(1,3), ("Click to close program: "))
                m.draw(w)
                w.getMouse()
                w.close()
```

This is how I finally solved it.

```
from graphics import *
from random import*
def main():
    print ("This program rolls dice using randint")

    w = GraphWin()
    s1 = Rectangle(Point(70,70), Point(20,20))
    s1.setFill("Green")
    s1.draw(w)

    s2 = Rectangle(Point(140, 140), Point (90,90))
    s2.setFill("Green")
    s2.draw(w)

    #Display message
    m = Text(Point(60,10), ("Click to roll dice: "))
    m.draw(w)
    #Define die faces
    center = Point(60,60)
    sd1 = Circle(center, 5)
    sd1.setFill("Red")

    center = Point(45,60)
    sd2 = Circle(center, 5)
    sd2.setFill("Red")

    center3 = Point(30,60)
    sd3 = Circle(center3, 5)
    sd3.setFill("Red")

    center4 = Point(30,30)
    sd4 = Circle(center4, 5)
    sd4.setFill("Red")

    center5 = Point(45,30)
    sd5 = Circle(center5, 5)
    sd5.setFill("Red")

    center6 = Point(60,30)
    sd6 = Circle(center6, 5)
    sd6.setFill("Red")

    center7 = Point(130,130)
    sd7 = Circle(center7, 5)
    sd7.setFill("Red")

    center8 = Point(130,115)
    sd8 = Circle(center8, 5)
    sd8.setFill("Red")

    center9 = Point(130,100)
    sd9 = Circle(center9, 5)
    sd9.setFill("Red")

    center10 = Point(100,100)
    sd10 = Circle(center10, 5)
    sd10.setFill("Red")

    center11 = Point(100,115)
    sd11 = Circle(center11, 5)
    sd11.setFill("Red")

    center12 = Point(100,130)
    sd12 = Circle(center12, 5)
    sd12.setFill("Red")


    #Set loops for each die
    w.getMouse()
    RN = randint(1,6)
    if RN == 1:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw(w)
    elif RN == 2:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw(w)
        sd2.draw(w)
    elif RN == 3:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw(w)
        sd2.draw(w)
        sd3.draw(w)
    elif RN == 4:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw(w)
        sd2.draw(w)
        sd3.draw(w)
        sd4.draw(w)
    elif RN == 5:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw(w)
        sd2.draw(w)
        sd3.draw(w)
        sd4.draw(w)
        sd5.draw(w)
    elif RN == 6:
        w.getMouse()
        sd1.draw(w)
        sd2.draw(w)
        sd3.draw(w)
        sd4.draw(w)
        sd5.draw(w)
        sd6.draw(w)

    w.getMouse()
    RN2 = randint(1,6)
    if RN2 == 1:
        w.getMouse()
        sd7.draw(w)
    elif RN2 == 2:
        w.getMouse()
        sd7.draw(w)
        sd8.draw(w)
    elif RN2 == 3:
        w.getMouse()
        sd7.draw(w)
        sd8.draw(w)
        sd9.draw(w)
    elif RN2 == 4:
        w.getMouse()
        sd7.draw(w)
        sd8.draw(w)
        sd9.draw(w)
        sd10.draw(w)
    elif RN2 == 5:
        w.getMouse()
        sd7.draw(w)
        sd8.draw(w)
        sd9.draw(w)
        sd10.draw(w)
        sd11.draw(w)
    elif RN2 == 6:
        w.getMouse()
        sd7.draw(w)
        sd8.draw(w)
        sd9.draw(w)
        sd10.draw(w)
        sd11.draw(w)
        sd12.draw(w)

    #Change message
    m.undraw()
    m2 = Text(Point(80,10), ("Click to close program: "))
    m2.draw(w)

    w.getMouse()
    w.close()

main()
```

Comment: Could you show the code you've tried so far? (It sounds like you've done part of the work and it would help anyone trying to answer)

Comment: Define what the dice face looks like for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6, then create a random integer from 1 to 6 and render that dice face.

Comment: Code added. I feel like I'm over-complicating it far too much, but as I said, I'm a beginner.

Comment: @Patashu: Thanks. Could you provide a brief example of what that might look like?

Comment: @Breck ODonnell Lots of ways - it could be an image that looks like the face. It could be a list of points (a point being a class with an x and a y), one point per dot on that face. It could be a two dimensional list, 3*3 size with false and true in each place indicating if there's a dot there or not. Etc... Pick the form that makes the most sense to you.

Comment: @Patashu Thanks very much, I think that will be quite helpful.

Comment: There's a lot of lines like "sd7.draw", which doesn't do anything. They should probably be function calls!

Comment: @boxed: A facepalm is in order here; you're right, although it would probably would have worked better if I had remembered to add (w) at the end of the draw commands.

Comment: I have some code that works; essentially the same as the second code in the original post, just correct with draw.(w) But the trouble is it requires me to write out every permutation of the dice numbers, which is ridiculous. Is there an equation or a loop that will let me do that simply?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

1. Create a list of all your faces of your dice.
2. When someone clicks the mouse, select a random integer between 0 and the number of faces on your dice.
3. Then take that number and use it as the subscript for your list of dice faces.
4. Display the dice face.

Since you asked about `randint`:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> randint(0,5)
2
>>> randint(0,5)
5
>>> randint(0,5)
1
```

So what you need now is this logic:

```
if mouse_click:
   random_number = randint(0,5)
   display_dice_face(dice_faces[random_number])
```

This is made easier since the `getMouse()` method will wait for a mouse click.

I think that should get you started.

Comment: I attempted the second code now shown in the main post. Theoretically it would seem to work, but the mouse click isn't doing anything. What have I left out?